# How to search in elasticsearch with Go filtering results by time frames

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I am retentively new to programming in Go.

I am trying create a simple program which does only one thing searches string via elasticsearch API.
My question is specific to the "[gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v2](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v2)" package I am using.

Here is a code sample:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v2"
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

type Syslog struct {
    Program   string
    Message   string
    Timestamp string
}


func main() {

    client, err := elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetURL("http://localhost:9200"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    info, code, err := client.Ping().Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Elasticsearch returned with code %d and version  %s", code, info.Version.Number)

    termQuery := elastic.NewTermQuery("message", "configuration")

    searchResult, err := client.Search().
        //PostFilter(postFilter).
        Index("logstash-*").     // search in index "logstash-*"
        Query(&termQuery).       // specify the query
        Sort("timestamp", true). // sort by "message" field, ascending
        From(0).Size(10).        // take documents 0-9
        Pretty(true).            // pretty print request and response JSON
        Do()                     // execute
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf(" Query took %d milliseconds\n", searchResult.TookInMillis)

    var ttyp Syslog

    for _, item := range searchResult.Each(reflect.TypeOf(ttyp)) {
        t := item.(Syslog)
        fmt.Printf("Found %s %s %s\n", t.Timestamp, t.Program, t.Message)
    }

}
```

This works, however what I really want is to limit search by time range.

As I understand I need to use FilteredQuery function. But I am lost in attempts to figure out how to create a filtered query.

There is function which created it "FilteredQuery" it requires Query Type as an input parameter but there is no function to create Query itself. I can just create a variable of a required type, still it need to have fields like which filed in elasticsearch to look for and a string to look for.

Same thing goes for the Filter variable in call for `func (FilteredQuery) Filter`.

May be someone has already got an example or can point me into the right direction.

I have an example of a JSON which if passed to elastcisearch gets me what I want:

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "message:\"configuration\"",
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": 1442100154219,
                  "lte": 1442704954219
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

But I do not know how to implement the same in Go. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See [`RangeFilter`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v2#RangeFilter) and [`FilteredQuery`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v2#FilteredQuery)

Here is an example producing the result you want :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    elastic "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v2"
)

func main() {

    termQuery := elastic.NewTermQuery("message", "configuration")

    timeRangeFilter := elastic.NewRangeFilter("@timestamp").Gte(1442100154219).Lte(1442704954219)

    // Not sure this one is really useful, I just put it here to mimic what you said is the expected result
    boolFilter := elastic.NewBoolFilter().Must(timeRangeFilter)

    query := elastic.NewFilteredQuery(termQuery).Filter(boolFilter)

    queryBytes, err := json.MarshalIndent(query.Source(), "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(queryBytes))
}
```

The output it produces is:

```
{
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "from": 1442100154219,
                            "include_lower": true,
                            "include_upper": true,
                            "to": 1442704954219
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "query": {
            "term": {
                "message": "configuration"
            }
        }
    }
}
```